# NextJS page urls to differ by language

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am making website that has different languages and i want the page urls to differ by language.

for example: www.website.com/anasayfa , www.website.com/home  same page but different url.

I am using this code  `<Link href="/home" as="/anasayfa">` but when I refresh page getting 404 not found error.

how can i make this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but there are 2 things that you will need to

1. Client side nav, as you suggested can be done with `<Link href="/home" as="/anasayfa">`
2. Server side, you will need to implement custom server, which will map this `/anasayfa` to the proper page.

```js
// server.js

const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  const pagesMap = {
    '/anasayfa': '/home',
  };

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    if (pagesMap.hasOwnProperty(req.pathname)) {
      return app.render(req, res, pagesMap[req.pathname], req.query);
    }

    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

My implementation is **super simple**, but think that you can make a DB request and load this map from it or any other complex solution

This snippet is based on [custom-server-express](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express).